# Is there a way or an query with which one can delete all the empty tables from Power BI's Query Editor in one go rather than manually removing them?

Tags: powerbi, ssms

I have extracted a large dataset in the form of different tables from SQL Server Management Studio into Power BI out of which maximum are empty tables with only headers and no data. I want to find a code with the help of which I can delete all such tables in one go rather than manually deleting each one.

I looked for this on ChatGPT and found some solutions which required changing the M-code in Power BI Query Editor in Advanced editor. But in that also I had to change the code for each table manually, which didn't serve the purpose.

**This is the code:**
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table.FromList(Source), {"Name"}, #"Table1", {"Name"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
FilterEmpty = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (Table.RowCount(Table1) > 0))
in
FilterEmpty

Answer (score 0):

Not natively. You might be able to do it via [Tabular Editor v2](https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor/releases/tag/2.22.0) with its [scripting capabilities](https://docs.tabulareditor.com/te2/Useful-script-snippets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Save the pbix as a [Power BI Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-overview) and all the different components will be saved as seperate files in a folder.  You can make changes directly to these files.